# Am using Tor now w/a VPN. How did MSN pinpoint my location? Screenshot

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, vpn, flash

What is going on? Am using Tor Browser along with "Strong VPN." Just signed out of my Hotmail which, at first, showed U.K. stories on its homepage.

But now that I'm about to sign back in, my real location in the U.A.E. seems to be revealed through MSN's home page.

What is going on? I must have been compromised. How is this possible? Anyone has any ideas on what I should do. What I should check? What I need to delete. I'm using, a Mac. Just updated to Yosemite while here in the U.A.E.

Too, I'm able to use Flash, watch YouTube, while using Tor Browser -- as per my previous question. I closed then restarted my laptop a few hours ago to semi-clean-up lagging programs.

I included a screenshot.

[image]

Also, my IP location -- when I do a "what is my IP" check -- shows the VPN location I connected to, which in this case is the U.K.

Please advise!

Comment: You appear to have Scripting enabled for this page. Maybe they have some javascript way to get your country or language from an environment variable. (I'm no expert in this area.)

Comment: There is no Flash support in the standard Tor Browser Bundle. Also no way for a web site to know your real IP address without help. Have you modified the browser settings in any way? Check the TBB signature of the official release against yours: https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en

Comment: Also, you have a lot of tabs open, potential to correlate behaviors across sites. Better to do a task, then do the next task with a new Tor identity (in the onion menu, or quit and restart Tor).

Comment: Went into my Terminal and GPG and verified the signature which was correct (thank god). Quit and restarted Tor. Didn't know about scripting. Just turned it off. Then temporarily allowed it for this site and to log back into MSN Hotmail then log out. Did a "what is my IP" in Google. So far, nothing shows my actual location. Thank you both for your input and helping me stay protected.

Comment: Also, just discovered that it was in fact HTML5 and not Flash. I just don't remember having any capability to watch any videos in Mavericks despite Tor's updates. Thank you again!

Comment: Too, top tip about the new identity and new Tor circuit with the onion. I've been using Tor on and off for a year or so and didn't know this. . . .

Comment: Are you sure you weren't logged in when you took this screen cap? It looks like you were. That would be the most obvious way to get your language / location preference

Comment: Hi there. No, I logged out, then went back. It "remembered" me. I guess scripting as mentioned earlier or cookies. I was using Tor and a VPN the entire time. The first time I signed out, was directed to MSN's U.K. homepage. I either closed that tab, or googled something on that tab afterwards. When I entered Hotmail/MSN again (either in the same or a new tab), I was greeted with a localized MSN homepage. The web address states that I had signed-out. My Hotmail settings have always been U..S.

Comment: Had to think about this again . . . everything I did above (scripting, quit and restart) seemed to correct the problem. But the original question still exists: how did MSN/Hotmail localize my page while using Tor and StrongVPN? Could having Hotmail on my iPhone have led to this even though my iPhone settings are U.S. English, etc.?